# PDF OPI (Open Prepress Interface), what are the steps to replace low resolution proxy with high resolution image?

Tags: postscript

There is close to none information about OPI on the internet, and there is none about replacing OPI with high resolution source image. Is there anyone that have any knowledge about it?

I have to both generate eps proxy with OPI link, and make a tool to be able to replace the OPI entries with high resolution source document.

The main problem that I have now is how to use %ALDImagePosition. The unit of this entry supposed to be in points (72 units per inch) how to relate that to %ALDImageDimensions and %ALDImageCropRect which are in pixels?
How to relate all those to original high resolution image?

If anyone could point me to any sources other than OPI reference manual, I would be very thankful. Other thing that I lack is any other software that would be able to do OPI replacement so I could test the files with OPI entries that I'm generating.

Edit1:
The whole workflow looks like this, high resolution source file (usually PDF, I know it sound weird) is converted into 2 low resolution images, one is placed into EPS body and is surrounded with OPI comments, the other goes to binary header of EPS. This makes an "EPS proxy". Those proxies are used in indesign or illustrator projects, and the output is saved to PDF. This PDF contains OPI entries from EPS proxies, that I need to replace back to high-res sources.

Going back to EPS with OPI, the specification says that %ALDImageDimensions gives dimensions of placed TIFF. What is the placed TIFF? The header image, body image or original high-res image? I'm setting this from body image.
It also says that %ALDImagePosition specifies where on the page the cropped portion of the image is to be printed. What is the page in this case? I guess that would be the bounding box of the EPS, right? But how do I get it from PDF I process? I'm trying to rely on OPI entries alone to calculate the scaling and cropping that is applied to high resolution document I'm replacing with.
What I do is in the PDF in the place of low-res image I inject the high-res one but for that I have to calculate transformation matrix. I did that by taking the size and position (also the crop rect) but those two are in different units so when my low-res image has resolution different than 72dpi the scaling is wrong.

This is the stream that I put in place of the low-res objects stream:

```
q
/GS0 gs
x x x x x x cm
/Fm0 Do
Q
```

What would be the steps for doing that correctly? What parameters are essential to take into account to fit the high-res in place of the low-res object?

This is the best I can explain the problem, this isn't easy to describe :)

Answer (score 1):

OPI is basically dead, it has been for years because these days nobody really cares about shuffling multi-megabyte images around.

The OPI manual is all there is, but I'm unclear on why you're having a problem. The whole point of OPI is that you don't really need to worry about this stuff.

The position is in points and the image dimensions are the number of image samples (or pixels if you prefer, but these are **image** pixels, not pixels on the output).

The high resolution image occupies the same area on the output as the low resolution image, but it has (obviously!) more image samples in each dimension.

To understand how this works you really need to understand how PostScript draws images which is non-trivial.

To use an image in PostScript you define an image dictionary which contains the image dimensions, the language maps these to 'the unit square', which is a square 1x1 points in size. It then uses the ImageMatrix (supplied in the dictionary) to scale that up to cover an area of the page. So an ImageMatrix [72 0 0 72 0 0] would cover 1 inch.

Crucially, this means the image covers one inch in the output, not matter how large the original image data is. This means I can 'swap out' the image and replace it with a higher resolution one by simply altering the Width and Height entries in the dictionary, and changing the image data.

Note that when it comes to OPI, the comments are only instructions to the OPI software, the PostScript interpreter ignores comments (anything beginning with %). There are two ways to replace the OPI images;

1) The PostScript interpreter is itself an OPI server. In this case it does not ignore the comments but acts upon them.

2) A pre-processor scans the PostScript program looking for OPI comments and uses them to identify and replace the low resolution images.

In either case there should be a pre-prepared high resolution OPI replacement. All that the server needs to do is identify the replacement and put it in the PostScript program in place of the low resolution one (which is delimited byt comments).

I've modified your tags because OPI isn't anything to do with EPS (although there are similar aims) and you can't do OPI with PDF.

Comment: "The PostScript file containing OPI comments should be either an EPS file or the multi-page equivalent of an EPS file" (OPI spec. 1.3)- so it does have something to do with EPS. And of course you can use OPI in PDF files. Just search OPI in PDF reference manual. I'll also expand my main question in couple of minutes. I even have trouble to formulate complete question, it is so confusing.

Comment: OPI was deprecated in PDF 2.0. Even before that it didn't work in (quite) the same way as PostScript. The OPI image has to be an EPS, yes, but that's not quite the same thing as this being an EPS-related question, it really isn't, you;re better off in PostScript. The reason the OPI image (both low and high resolution) is EPS (in PostScript OPI) is so that you can remove the low resolution one and insert the high resolution one in its place.

Comment: Yeah but PDF 2.0 is only a bit more that 2 years old. I don't know why we insist on using OPI but that's what I have to deal with right now. I guess this lets create lighter documents that work faster while processing. Is there any particular new tech in 2.0 that lets us do similar thing then?

Comment: No, sorry, the whole idea has been deprecated really because nobody cares about big files any more, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The thing that you may not understand about my approach is that the high-res source is mostly PDF. I'm taking the whole pdf and placing it as an XObject form. It scales differently than image at least that what I encountered. This is really messed up :). I ignore old transformation matrices that are in the OPI objects stream and I calculate my own.

Comment: Well I'm not surprised you're having trouble finding references. The OPI specification was written for PostScript, not PDF. While PDF does (or more accurately did) support PDF I'm not aware of any implementations. I'm unclear on what you are doing, or want to do; 'taking the whole pdf and placing it as an XObject' doesn't really tell me much, I'd need a concrete example file to discuss in order to be able to offer suggestions. Are you using OPI 1.3 or 2.0, where is the image substitution to take place, server or printer ?